# Why can you shortcircuit a car battery with a wrench in your hand and stay safe?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, batteries, short-circuits

In [this demonstration](https://youtu.be/ViwSDL657L4?list=PLyQSN7X0ro2314mKyUiOILaOC2hk6Pc3j&t=30m45s) by Prof. Walter Lewin a car battery is shortcircuited with a wrench. The experimenter is holding the wrench in its bare hands, so why he is not experiences an electric shock? Should there not flow current through him (as the human body is a conductor) to the ground?

Comment: Please do not try this at home.  While in the case of lead acid car batteries, they have high internal resistance which limits the current flow through a metal object, other batteries have extremely small internal resistance which will allow high current flow which can be deadly.

Comment: "While in the case of lead acid car batteries, they have high internal resistance" About 0.02 ohm. Is that high?

Comment: If the current gets too high and the battery explodes, you will get boiling sulfuric acid sprayed all over you.  DON'T try this at home.

Comment: When I was four I wanted to see electricity. So I got an old lamp cord that was laying around the house and stripped off the insulation on the wires. Then I thought, if the electricity spills out onto the floor my parents will see it and know I was up to no good. So I stripped the wires on the other end and twisted them together. Then I pushed the bare ends into a wall socket. The resulting noise followed by darkness was exciting. But it caused my father to appear asking "Dan! What are you doing?" ... "Nothing."

Comment: Heh heh.   https://www.cartoonstock.com/cartoon?searchID=CS302983

Comment: @Dan So you never got to see it?

Answer (score 4):

It would be extremely dangerous to short-circuit a car battery using a wrench (spanner) held in your hand, but not because of electric shock; this would hardly be felt for a 12 V battery, or even for a 24 V battery, as the body's resistance, arising mainly at the points of contact, is too high. The danger is because, if left across the battery terminals, the wrench would rapidly get very hot, as would the acid in the battery. A modern battery might not burst but it would very likely spurt hot acid.

Why this quick temperature rise? Car batteries are made to supply very high currents (240 A would not be unusual) to a starter motor for a short time. They can do this only because of their very low internal resistance; 0.02 ohm would be quite typical. A wrench, being a short, thick bar of metal, will also have a very low resistance (probably less than 0.05 ohm) so a 12 V battery will drive a current in the order of 200 A through it. This current will, of course, pass through the battery, too. You can calculate the power dissipations in the spanner and the battery. They speak for themselves.

Comment: Depends very much on the type of battery. Some as high as 600 Amps.  https://lifelinebatteries.com/2020/08/how-much-electricity-do-car-batteries-produce/   Still, I^2 R means at 600 Amps it's 7.2 KW, enough to make the battery get warm quite fast.

Comment: @Dan I was deliberately being conservative in my figures!

Answer (score 3):

Current always flows in a loop. In this case, from the battery, through the wrench, and back to the battery. The experimenter's body does not provide a path for current in that loop. It would be different if the experimenter left the wrench in the toolbox and simply grabbed the '+' terminal with one hand and the '-' terminal with the other. In that case, current would flow in a loop from the battery, through the experimenter, and back to the battery.

**BUT**

A car battery only supplies 12 Volts. That's not enough voltage to push a lethal current through two small patches of somebody's dry skin. Probably not even enough to push a lethal current through two small patches of salty, wet skin.

Comment: So, the ground does not have a different potential then either of both terminals? I think this makes no sense, it must have a different potential from either '+' or '-', or not?

Comment: @StefanH the resistance of the tires and shoes, which would be part of the return current to the battery, is probably GIgaohms. So there is current through the experimenter, but it is unnoticeably small.

Comment: @tobalt: Ok, thank you. Btw, in the same lecture series, he talks about the resistance of shoes, see https://youtu.be/PJqOaHBgr30?list=PLyQSN7X0ro2314mKyUiOILaOC2hk6Pc3j&t=44m00s

Comment: There is a risk of a burn or eye damage from the arc which can occur when the contact is made or broken.

Comment: @StefanH, _Current always flows in a loop._ Without any electrical connection between the battery and Earth, there is no path for current to flow from the battery, through the person, _and back to the battery._ You are correct in assuming that the potential between Earth and '+' cannot be the same as the potential between Earth and '-', but without that electrical connection between the other parts of the circuit and Earth, those potentials are undefined.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sorry, I do not understand that explanation. When I am touching a door knob and get an electric shock, this "undefined" potential difference becomes quite real...

Comment: @StefanH, "real" and "defined" don't mean the same thing. Before you touched that door knob, the "undefined" potential between it and your finger may _really_ have been thousands of Volts, but the amount of charge probably was so small that it would have been difficult to measure the Voltage without substantially depleting it. The potential almost instantly became a well-defined zero Volts when your finger touched it. It happened so quickly that the Voltage and current both were zero before you had any awareness of the spark or the shock.

Comment: I am grounded, and the voltage can be deduced from the amount of charge on the door knob. Hence, theoretically, it has a well-defined value. Surely, me touching it is like shortcircuiting and hence the voltage drops immediately to zero, but before I am touching it I guess it has a well-defined value. This seems to contradict what you are saying...

Comment: @StefanH, You are talking about "static" electricity. I don't know a lot about that. I only know a little bit about electronic _circuits,_ and in circuit theory, the voltage between any two points that are not part of the _same_ circuit is "undefined." Your original question was about a circuit that consisted of a car battery, a wrench, and maybe a human body. Any discussion about the static charge on a door knob is getting somewhat off the original topic, and it's entering territory where I do not feel competent to participate.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I was not aware that different "theories" apply here. Thought there is one physical explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> so why he is not experiences an electric shock? Should there not flow
> current through him (as the human body is a conductor) to the ground?

The basic reason is the current through the body from a 12 volt source, under dry contact conditions, would be too low. Although the available current from the battery is very high, the voltage is too low to drive enough current through the body.

The body's electrical resistance is primarily the skin resistance under dry or slightly moist contact, and is a function of voltage among other things. The higher the voltage the lower the resistance, and vice versa.

IEC 60479-1 (Effects of current on human beings and livestock), indicates that the body impedance at 25 vdc, from hand to hand, for the general population varies between 2100 $\Omega$ (for 5% of the population) to 7275 $\Omega$ (for 95% of the population). (A hand to hand current path would be from the wrench, held by one hand, with the other hand touching some other metal part of the chassis which is connected to the negative battery terminal).

So conservatively taking the lower value of impedance and applying Ohm's law, the current the battery can deliver in a path hand to hand through the body would be about 6 mA dc, which is well below the dc threshold of ventricular fibrillation according to IEC 60479-1.

That said, the car battery can certainly deliver a lot of current with a high amount of $I^{2}R$ heating, posing a possible burn hazard.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But as written here https://academic.oup.com/ptj/article-abstract/46/9/968/4637975?redirectedFrom=PDF a current of 10mA is capable of producing pain or shock. From considering the numbers, 6mA does not seem so far away from 10mA (but maybe I have no real intuition on that)...

Comment: I go by the authoritative sources, such as IEC 60479-1.  For dc, 6 mA is just above the threshold for reaction ( 5 mA dc) and well below the level of serious electric shock (well over 100 ma dc). 7-10 mA is the  ac threshold for inability to let go . As I recall inability to let go only applies to ac, not dc. In any case, the term "electric shock" is meaningless unless you specify the physiological effect of concern (i.e., reaction, inability to let go, ventricular fibrillation, cardiac arrest, electrical burns, etc.). Clearly the history with 12 v car batteries shows no electric shock hazard.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries generate power based on chemical reactions and in these reactions the charge should be neutralized. And hence the amount of charges lost from negative terminal should be equal to the amount of charges gained by positive terminal then only will the reaction proceed and would maintain the EMF between two terminals. Also let's say that somehow you manage to get rid of this concept still the amount of current flowing through the body will be small with respect to the wrench because wrench has less resistance than your body and hence maximum current would channel through the wrench.